# Convert dropdownlist into text

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have designed a dropdownlist for the entry of date. Now I have to convert it into text format (like the way you enter into a text field - mm-dd-yyyy) so that I can display it in an xml file.

Any suggestions on how to go about it?

My frontend code looks like this. This is just one part of it. I have 3 more entities like this.:

```
  <td>
      LICENSE FROM *
  </td>
  <td>
      &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="drpmm0" runat="server" CssClass="drp1">
      </asp:DropDownList>
      &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="drpdte0" runat="server" CssClass="drp1">
      </asp:DropDownList>
      &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="drpyyyy0" runat="server" CssClass="drp1">
      </asp:DropDownList>
      &nbsp;(mm-dd-yyyy)
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqmm0" runat="server" ControlToValidate="drpmm0" Display="Dynamic"ErrorMessage="Select Month"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqdte0" runat="server" ControlToValidate="drpdte0" ErrorMessage="Select Date"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqyyyy0" runat="server" ControlToValidate="drpyyyy0" ErrorMessage="Select Year"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
</tr>
```

I just need a little guidance for backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string strdt= drpdte0.SelectedValue+"/"+drpmm0.SelectedValue+"/"+drpyyyy0.SelectedValue;
string formatedDate = strdt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: I want to convert the dropdownlist into a text format by combining the three values, which would not be shown on my page but stored internally. Now I want to use this value and display it in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `DateTimePicker`?

Comment: i can't use datetimepicker because I'm making my program on a web page.

Comment: I know you coding on wed program ,you also can download some time control like My97DatePicker,it works better than you use now，

Answer (score 0):

To get into string:

```
string myDate = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", drmm0.SelectedValue, drpdte0.SelectedValue, drpyyy0);
```

To get into DateTime:

```
DateTime myDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(drpyyyy0.SelectedValue)), Convert.ToInt32(drpmm0.SelectedValue),Convert.ToInt32(drpdte0.SelectedValue)));
```

Format DateTime:

```
string myDate = String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", myDate);
```